# Seg Fault Error C++, When Creating a 2d dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, graph

I am creating a 2d dynamic array in order to represent a directed graph. I set all the values to false. Then as I get the data from a file I set the appropriate row/column combination to true to represent that the row has a directed edge towards the column. However, I am getting a seg fault. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to fix the seg fault and all help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Graph{
    public:
        string nodes;
        bool **A;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "No file was given as an argument, and the program will end now." << endl;
        return 0;    }

    ifstream graph ( argv[1]);

    Graph myGraph;//graph object
    string num;

    int tempNum;
    int tempNum2;
    int tracker = 0;

    while (graph.good())
    {
      graph >> num ;

      if( tracker == 0) {// if first number then create array
            myGraph.nodes = num;

            myGraph.A = new bool * [tempNum];
            int i, m, n;
            for (i = 0; i < tempNum; i++ ){
                myGraph.A[i] = new bool [tempNum];
                        }

            //set all to false
            for (m = 0; m < tempNum; m++) {
                for(n = 0; n < tempNum; n++){
                    myGraph.A[n][m] = false; }}

            tracker++;}//end of if tracker = 0

    else {//otherwise make connection true in 2d array
        if(tracker % 2 == 1){
            stringstream convert(num);
            int tempNum;
            convert >> tempNum;
            tracker++;
            }
        else if(tracker % 2 == 0) {

        stringstream convert(num);
        int tempNum2;
        convert >> tempNum2; 

        myGraph.A[tempNum][tempNum2] = true;
        tracker++;
                }
        }

    }//end of while
    cout << myGraph.A[5][5] << "should be false " << false << endl;
    cout << myGraph.A[3][2] << "should be false " << false << endl;
    cout << myGraph.A[4][6] << "should be false " << false << endl;
    cout << myGraph.A[8][9] << "should be true: " << true << endl;
    cout << myGraph.A[7][5] << "should be true: " << true << endl;
    cout << myGraph.A[2][4] << "should be true: " << true << endl;
graph.close();

return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new local `tempNum` variable in this block:

```
    if(tracker % 2 == 1){
        stringstream convert(num);
        int tempNum;                  // <<<<<<<<<<<<
        convert >> tempNum;
        tracker++;
        }
```

It will shadow the one declared earlier:

```
int tempNum;                          // <<<<<<<<<<<<
int tempNum2;
int tracker = 0;
```

Therefore the first index here will be undefined (the original variable again, which has not been assigned to ever):

```
    myGraph.A[tempNum][tempNum2] = true;
```

That causes a memory access violation and the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few observations:

- `tempNum` is not initialized before it is used in `if (tracker == 0)` branch. So 2d array allocation size is undefined.
- Also, declaration `int tempNum` in `if (tracker %2 == 1)` branch shadows the earlier declaration right before start of `while (graph.good())` loop. By the end of the branch, this declaration is no longer effective, so that the value obtained is not used in the `if (tracker % 2 == 0))` branch.